# How to use renderer in column ui component grid in magento 2

Tags: magento2, grid, uicomponent, renderer

I want to use renderer on certain column of grid.I need hint/suggestion.I used this tutorial for creating a grid in magneto2
https://ranasohel.me/2014/04/20/creating-magento2-adminhtml-grid/.
I used ui_component for creating a grid.Because in magento 2 ui_component use xml to display grid.

**app/code/Test/Testimonial/view/adminhtml/ui_component/testimonial_blog_listing.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">testimonial_blog_listing.testimonial_blog_listing_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">testimonial_blog_listing.testimonial_blog_listing_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">testimonial_blog_columns</item>
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="add" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add New testimonial</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/new</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="testimonial_blog_listing_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">PostGridDataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">testimonial_blog_listing_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">entity_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <container name="listing_top">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/toolbar</item>
                <item name="stickyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/sticky/toolbar</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <bookmark name="bookmarks">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">testimonial_blog_listing</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </bookmark>
        <component name="columns_controls">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="columnsData" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">testimonial_blog_listing.testimonial_blog_listing.testimonial_blog_columns</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/controls/columns</item>
                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">dataGridActions</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </component>
        <exportButton name="export_button">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">testimonial_blog_listing.testimonial_blog_listing.testimonial_blog_columns.ids</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </exportButton>
        <filterSearch name="fulltext">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">testimonial_blog_listing.testimonial_blog_listing_data_source</item>
                    <item name="chipsProvider" xsi:type="string">testimonial_blog_listing.testimonial_blog_listing.listing_top.listing_filters_chips</item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">testimonial_blog_listing.testimonial_blog_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.search</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </filterSearch>
        <filters name="listing_filters">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="columnsProvider" xsi:type="string">testimonial_blog_listing.testimonial_blog_listing.testimonial_blog_columns</item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">testimonial_blog_listing.testimonial_blog_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.filters</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="templates" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="filters" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="select" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select</item>
                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">testimonial_blog_listing.testimonial_blog_listing.listing_top.listing_filters</item>
                        <item name="imports" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="visible" xsi:type="string">testimonial_blog_listing.testimonial_blog_listing.testimonial_blog_columns.${ $.index }:visible</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <item name="observers" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="column" xsi:type="string">column</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </filters>
        <massaction name="listing_massaction">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">testimonial_blog_listing.testimonial_blog_listing.testimonial_blog_columns.ids</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <action name="delete">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">delete</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="testimonial/blog/massDelete"/>
                        <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete items</item>
                            <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure you wan't to delete selected items?</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>
            <action name="disable">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">disable</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Disable</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="testimonial/blog/massDisable"/>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>
            <action name="enable">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">enable</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Enable</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="testimonial/blog/massEnable"/>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>
        </massaction>
        <paging name="listing_paging">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">testimonial_blog_listing.testimonial_blog_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.paging</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">testimonial_blog_listing.testimonial_blog_listing.testimonial_blog_columns.ids</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </paging>
    </container>
    <columns name="testimonial_blog_columns">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">testimonial_blog_listing.testimonial_blog_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current</item>
                </item>
                <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">testimonial_blog_listing.testimonial_blog_listing.testimonial_blog_columns_editor</item>
                        <item name="target" xsi:type="string">startEdit</item>
                        <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="0" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                            <item name="1" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">testimonial_blog_listing.testimonial_blog_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="root" xsi:type="string">columns.${ $.index }</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.${ $.storageConfig.root}</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <selectionsColumn name="ids">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">55</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </selectionsColumn>
        <column name="entity_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                    <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ID</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="title">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Title</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="publish_date" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Publish Date</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="price">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Price</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <actionsColumn name="actions" class="SR\testimonial\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\PostAction">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
                    <item name="viewUrlPath" xsi:type="string">testimonial/blog/edit</item>
                    <item name="urlEntityParamName" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </actionsColumn>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 13):

You can renderer grid column as follow

For Example to simple add "Test" with column values.

1) Define you renderer class to column `Vendor\Modulename\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Yourcolumn`

> Vendor/Modulename/view/adminhtml/ui_component/your_grid.xml

```
<column name="yourcolumn" class="Vendor\Modulename\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Yourcolumn">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">false</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Column Label</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>
```

2) Now you can do anything with column data in renderer file

> Vendor/Modulename/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/Yourcolumn.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Modulename\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

class Yourcolumn extends \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column {

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ){
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }

    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource) {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {

            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {

                //$item['yourcolumn'] is column name
                $item['yourcolumn'] = $item['yourcolumn']."Test"; //Here you can do anything with actual data

            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no renderer involved here, just modifying the data that is then rendered...

Comment: Here I  get actual data and attach test with each actual data. Please explain what is renderer in your language?

Comment: @PrincePatel Do you know how to return HTML from renderer prepareDataSource function?

Comment: Pass your html in __$item['yourcolumn'] = "<h1>Test</h1>"__  and add `<item name="bodyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/cells/html</item>` in column config.

Comment: Yr Welcome @chiragdodia.

Comment: @PrincePatel how to use renderer if column is not present in collection

Comment: @faizanbeg Please ask another question with full details.

Comment: @PrincePatel i need to add a column using ui component name as customcolumn but it not present in data collection as other columns i just want to show 4000 as text in this coulmn in grid

Comment: Will filtering on this column still work if this changes are made?

Comment: @PrincePatel, but this rendered column does not show any value in Exported CSv sheet, see this URL https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47086239/magento-2-custom-rendered-data-not-exporting

Comment: Hi @Prince Patel, Rendered column ascending descending not working. Can you please suggest.

Answer (score 3):

You can use renderer in as follow

For Example I was getting country_id and I wanted to display whole Country Name in grid so I used renderer for it

In your ui component grid xml add column

```
<column name="country_codes" class="Vender\Modulename\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Countries">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Directory\Model\Config\Source\Country</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">multiselect</item>
            <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
            <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Countries</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>
```

Your Renderer File

```
<?php

namespace Vender\Modulename\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

class Countries extends \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column {

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Directory\Api\CountryInformationAcquirerInterface
     */
    protected $countryInformation;

     /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory
     * @param \Magento\Directory\Api\CountryInformationAcquirerInterface $countryInformation
     * @param array $components
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        \Magento\Directory\Api\CountryInformationAcquirerInterface $countryInformation,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ){
        $this->countryInformation = $countryInformation;
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Prepare Data Source
     *
     * @param array $dataSource
     * @return array
     */
    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource) {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            $fieldName = $this->getData('name');
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
                $countryNames = [];
                $countryCodes = [];
                if(!empty($item[$fieldName])){
                    $countryCodes = explode(',', $item[$fieldName]);
                }
                foreach($countryCodes as $codes){
                    $country = $this->countryInformation->getCountryInfo($codes);
                    $countryNames[] = $country->getFullNameLocale();
                }
                $item[$fieldName] = implode(',', $countryNames);
            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no renderer involved here, just modifying the data that is then rendered...

Comment: What you exactly want to do?

Comment: but this rendered column does not show any value in Exported CSv sheet, see this URL https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47086239/magento-2-custom-rendered-data-not-exporting.

Comment: Data not coming in export

Answer (score 0):

**Found it.**

There's no "renderer" when it comes to UI Component, instead you need to use the `bodyTmpl` param to set a custom .html template for the cell, like this:

```xml
<listing>
  [...]
  <columns>
    <column name="column_name_in_database">
      <settings>
        <filter>text</filter>
        <label translate="true">Some Label</label>

        <!-- here's the trick -->
        <bodyTmpl>YourVendor_YourModule/ui/grid/cells/code</bodyTmpl>

        <!-- you can also add a css class into the <td> as below -->
        <fieldClass>
          <class name="myclass">true</class>
        </fieldClass>
      </settings>
    </column>
    [..]
  </columns>
</listing>
```

Then create the template in *app/code/YourVendor/YourModule/view/adminhtml/web/template/ui/grid/cells/code.html* and fill it with the desired custom html:

```html
<!-- /**
 * @see vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/templates/grid/cells/text.html
*/ -->
<code class="data-grid-cell-content" text="$col.getLabel($row())"></code>
```

> **Tip:** To see the available row data in the template, you can use this:

```html
<pre data-bind='text: ko.toJSON($row().status, null, 2)'></pre>
```

[Real-world example](https://github.com/discorgento/module-queue) · [Official documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/ui_comp_guide/components/ui-column.html)