# Magento 2:Store View in Ui Component Form

Tags: magento2, adminform, uicomponent

I have displayed an admin form using UiComponent form. As one of my admin field I want to display all store views in a multi-select field.

Please help me with a solution.

Comment: Use renderer in your xml file. For more information , Follow this link http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/120606/how-to-use-renderer-in-column-ui-component-grid-in-magento-2

Answer (score 11):

Add following code into your ui_component form

```
<field name="storeviews">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Cms\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Cms\Options</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">int</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Store View</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">multiselect</item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">page</item>
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">store_id</item>
            <item name="default" xsi:type="string">0</item>
            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked .But just need to end tag item in line 3

Comment: I just updated, check now.