# Need help with ui component and change sorting order of columns in magento 2

Tags: magento2, database, uicomponent, sorting

Have listing but need to change view of one column:

```
    <column name="status">
        <settings>
            <filter>text</filter>
            <label translate="true">Status</label>
        </settings>
    </column>
```

i need to display text as value instead of integer value since in database it has 0 or 1 so in overview i have numerical values.

also another question how to change sorting order of columns since it seem i have actions column in front of some other fields although in xml it's placed as last item

Comment: Check this for int value to text : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/120606/how-to-use-renderer-in-column-ui-component-grid-in-magento-2

Comment: thx, this solved my view problem, now need to change sorting

Comment: Glad to hear this. So You wanted to sort fields ? In grid listing ?

Comment: yes, in grid listing i need to sort available fields. used mage2gen site to create base structure for my module.

Comment: Try this. `<item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">6</item>`

Comment: wel it seem sort order is negated if grid was already loaded. had to clean ui_bookmark
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4620

Comment: Yes, Dont you know about that. All grid's sort order store into ui_bookmark table. I've added answer if you think it resolve your issue you can accept and give upvote to help community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change int value to text you can use below code :

```
<column name="yourcolumn" class="Vendor\Modulename\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Yourcolumn">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">false</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Column Label</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>
```

Ref : https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/171412/49826