# How to show Product Attribute name in column?

Tags: magento2, custom-admin-grid

I Have a custom table that saves product attribute Id. For E.g

```
id, color_id, brand_id
1,123,122
```

Now I wanted to show attribute option value( Color name, brand name) on Admin grid of custom module.

I have added new columns  in _initSelect() function in collection.php file  as follow.

```
$this->getSelect()->columns(array(
         'brand' => new \Zend_Db_Expr('(select value from eav_attribute_option_value where  option_id = brand_id)')
     ));
$this->getSelect()->columns(array(
         'color' => new \Zend_Db_Expr('(select value from eav_attribute_option_value where  option_id = color_id)')
     ));
```

But, After adidng above I am not getting values in grid.

```
<column name="brand">
    <settings>
        <filter>text</filter>
        <label translate="true">Brand</label>
        <editor>
            <editorType>text</editorType>
            <validation>
                <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</rule>
            </validation>
        </editor>
    </settings>
</column>

<column name="color">
    <settings>
        <filter>text</filter>
        <label translate="true">Brand</label>
        <editor>
            <editorType>text</editorType>
            <validation>
                <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</rule>
            </validation>
        </editor>
    </settings>
</column>
```

How can we display name instead of attribute Id in grid?

Comment: Try this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/120606/how-to-use-renderer-in-column-ui-component-grid-in-magento-2

Comment: This is like adding a renderer class. Is there any option without it?